# componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть модальное окно, которое должно закрываться по ескейпу но не закрывается

в консоли я вижу свою функцию но она почему то не вызывается
эта же функция на кнопках работает нормально

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: я даже хз что добавить, там все просто:
через пропс передаю функцию, пытаюсь вызвать внутри ифа но оно не срабатывает, хотя в консоле я вижу эту функцию то есть вроде нормально вроде все приходит

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Но в виде скринов, а в виде текста, с указанием, что именно в коде работает не так или не работает

Comment: я незнаю как реакт добавить в код

Comment: кстати вынес функцию отдельно и заработало

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вынести отдельно то работает, почему так не знаю, ну ладно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).